# TDD for Java Command-line program and nested readLine()

Tags: java, command-line, junit, tdd

Basically, I'm writing a Java Command-line application which accept parameter from user by readLine. Ex, if the user press "1" it will ask which book the user wants to check out, the user can press the number of the book by "1" or "2" ... So, the application accepts user parameter two times. And I'm trying to use TDD to test the application alongside as well.

Here is the problem. 
If I do something like this to simulate user input

```
System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(PRESS_TWO.getBytes())); // set the first option

Program.main(new String[]{}); // run the program

System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream(PRESS_ONE.getBytes())); // set the second option
```

The first step that waits for user to choose option is ok, but it will go right through the second step without waiting for the second input. How can I simulate this in **JUnit**?

Thanks

This is how I read input

```
 try {

            i1 = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Enter a valid integer!!");
        }

        if (i1 == 1) {
            System.out.println(" 1. Book1 ");
            System.out.println(" 2. eBook2 ");
            System.out.println(" 3. Book3 ");
        }
        else if (i1 == 2) {
            System.out.println(" Which one do you want?: ");
            int i2 = 0;
            try {
                i2 = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                // Do you know what numbers are!!!
                System.out.println("Enter a valid integer!!");

            }
       }
```

Comment: One of the great things about test driven development is that it can highlight design issues.  I personally would take the difficulty you're having with this as a sign you might have a problem with your design.  You might consider breaking up your logic.  First, have an input controller.  Test that thoroughly.  Then perhaps you need a menu view.  Then perhaps a book retrieval controller that takes a book number.  Each of these is far easier to test, and in making the program easier to test, you've now also made it more modular, and each piece is more reusable.

Comment: Marvo, if you had that as an answer I'd upvote it, fo sho.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to change my design to State Pattern which is much more easier to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how your code reads the input, but I would assume that once the end of the first `ByteArrayInputStream` is reached, your code sees end-of-file and terminates. Try to combine the two streams into one (separated by a newline).

Comment: Note that `main` will run to completion (or until an exception is thrown) even before the second stream is set. The first `reader.readLine()` will succeed, but the second one will probably return `null` since it sees that the end of the (first) stream has been reached (what is the type of `reader`, by the way?). When `Integer.parseInt()` receives `null`, it will throw an exception, which will get caught, and `main()` will terminate normally.

Comment: Can I do something to pause it and accept the second parameter? I'm looking at SequenceInputStream but it's not working.

Comment: Not unless you restructure the code and split up the method; coroutines (methods that can "leave" at a certain point and resume execution from the same point later) do not exist in Java. You might want to look at @Marvo's suggestions. But is there a reason you can't just give it all the user input in one stream?